# object $Button within foreach / how to reference it to change color

Tags: powershell

I'm building GUI using foreach,
Now... could do 16 buttons but trying to automate build a little:

`1,2,3,4 | foreach { $Button...}`

all this works and I get 16 buttons with correct offsets but got stuck a little when decided to use jobs within buttons, background job pings, sleeps, pings - if fail to ping job ends and at this point I want it to change button's color

Since all buttons are "$Button",

can foreach generate $button with different number at the end? ie $Button1, $Button2... etc ?
tried $Button$_ but this didn't work

or any thoughts on how to reference buttons so depending on which job finished could change color of that button?

Cheers

@Wasif_Hasan this didn't work

```
$i=120
1..4 | Foreach {Set-Variable -Name "Button$($_)" -Value "Value"
$i=$i+70
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,$i)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$Button.Text = 'Cancel'+$_
$Button.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $Button
$form.Controls.Add($Button)
}
$Button3.Text = 'ok'+$_
```

Error:

```
The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

Code that can be saved as .PS1 to check...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select a Computer'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,400)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$i=10
1..4 | Foreach {Set-Variable -Name "Button$($_)" -Value "Value"
$i=$i+50
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,$i)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$Button.Text = "Number"+$_
$form.Controls.Add($Button)
}
$Button3.Text = "Test"
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
```

Error:

```
The property 'Text' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property 
exists and can be set.
At line:19 char:1
+ $Button3.Text = "Test"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Solution, Thanks Wasif_Hasan!

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'Select a Computer'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,400)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Button=1,2,3,4
$i=10

$k=1
1,2,3,4 | Foreach {
$i=$i+50


    New-Variable "Button$_" -Value $(new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
        Name = 'Dvar'
        Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,$i)
        Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
        Text = $_
    })

    $form.Controls.Add($(Get-Variable "Button$_" -ValueOnly))


$k=$k++
}
$Button2.Text="Hello"
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
$k=5
Remove-Variable Button*
$form.ActiveControl.Text
```

Result:
1
Hello
2
3

Comment: The code you've posted above, as someone elses, clearly is not what they provided as you've added much more to it, including a lone closing brace, which makes the code unlikely to work. In order to receive focused assistance with your issue, could you provide a [mcve] of some representative code for potential responders, to assist you with.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to deal with a collection instead of 16 individually named variables?

Comment: Yes @Compo I've added Wasif_Hasan's suggestion to my code, so yes, 2nd line is his code... Not sure how much smaller can this example be... it creates 4 buttons and later want to change Button 3 text...

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen not sure what would this change?

Comment: Nothing related to this question, it was more of an orthogonal question really.

Comment: @PawelD, I'm not sure if you noticed in my previous comment, but I identified that you had posted code which has unbalanced braces, it is clear therefore that your code does not work as posted, and/or you've omittted code which would allow us to reproduce your issue. If I was to run a `.ps1` file with that content, I do not believe that it would produce the output `Error` you have shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to set them use this:

```
1..4 | Foreach {Set-Variable -Name "Button$($_)" -Value "Value"}
```

And you can also get the values like:

```
1..4 | Foreach {(Get-Variable -Name "Button$($_)").Value}
```

All will be created like $Button1,$Button2 etc.

Comment: Will this make "$Button" unique ?
```
$i=120
1..4 | Foreach {Set-Variable -Name "Button$($_)" -Value "Value"
$i=$i+70
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,$i)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$Button.Text = 'Cancel'+$_
$Button.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $Button
$form.Controls.Add($Button)
}```

Sorry cannot format it correctly in comment